# Need to copy a file using wget in windows

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
class demo
{
public static void main(String str[]) throws Exception
{
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wget -P C:\vignesh\Docx\docx_final\Html2Docx\src http://anbu/upload/ExportHtml.html");
     p.destroy();
}
}
```

Hi all,

I want to copy a file from URL to my folder(src). I tried through java, i got error illegal escape character. but the above wget works in command prompt. Please help me..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the code to compile you need to escape the '\' characters in your call to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

The second problem you will have is that your call to `p.destroy()` is terminating the process before it has completed. You can either delete the call or, if you wish to do further processing once the download has completed, call `p.waitFor()`.

Your code would then look like this:

```
class demo {
    public static void main( String str[] ) throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "wget -P C:\\vignesh\\Docx\\docx_final\\Html2Docx\\src http://anbu/upload/ExportHtml.html"" );
        p.waitFor();
        // do more processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well "\" should be escaped to "\\" in Java strings.

Comment: I changed like "wget -P C:\\vignesh\\Docx\\docx_final\\Html2Docx\\src anbu/upload/ExportHtml.html".It doesn't show error but the file is not copied(any changed to be done in URL part?)

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\vignesh\Docx\docx_final\Html2Docx\src
->
C:\\vignesh\\Docx\\docx_final\\Html2Docx\\src
```

Comment: I changed like "wget -P C:\\vignesh\\Docx\\docx_final\\Html2Docx\\src http://anbu/upload/ExportHtml.html".It doesn't show error but the file is not copied(any changed to be done in URL part?)